# GEF : automatic scrolling during drag and drop

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef

I have a graphical editor written with GEF. In this editor it's possible to drag and drop elements around and create connection by dragging and dropping on specific anchor points.

Everything works fine, except that the diagram does not automatically scroll when the user drags stuff around.

I would expect the diagram to scroll automatically when the user reaches the side of it while dragging something.

Is such a feature supported by GEF? Which class/setter should be called to enable it?

If it's not directly supported, how to proceed to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I last fiddled with GEF.

Does drag and drop not work at all or just in the direction of negative coordinates?
What Layout are you using?

IIRC, there were different layouts with one of them (FreeForm?) supporting negative coordinates, so if you just have trouble with negative coords, you could try to change the Layout.

Here is an example of a [Scrolling Graphical editor](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/pde-incubator/visualization/plugins/org.eclipse.gef/src/org/eclipse/gef/ui/parts/ScrollingGraphicalViewer.java.shtml) (the author says ;)) which might give you a good hint.

And there is a class named *org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.ScrollingGraphicalViewer* that might help, too.

Only hints, though, since I don't know your code.

Answer (score 3):

First step is to make your canvas scrollable. This is explained [in this book](http://www.worlduc.com/UploadFiles/BlogFile/36%5C1131673%5C1.pdf), pages **96 - 101**.

Assuming you are already drawing your figures on a `FigureCanvas` and you're using `FreeformFigure`s and `FreeformLayer`, you can do the following:

Add a `MouseMoveListener` on your `Figure` in its `EditPart`. Each time a drag is detected, in the `mouseDragEvent` method, reveal your figure with `getViewer().reveal(EditPart.this)`.

This will cause your `Figure` to always be constantly revealed when it's being dragged.

Comment: Could you also name the book title and author? The link above is not working any more.

Comment: @Simon "The Eclipse Graphical Editing Framework (GEF)" by Dan Rubel, Jaime Wren and Eric Clayberg. It's part of "the eclipse series". The book's covers is white with dark purple.